# Why does !x change 1 and 0 to true / false

Tags: javascript, jquery

so here is my example code - http://jsfiddle.net/JRqq3/ .

It outputs true/false instead of 0/1 why so?

Code -

```
x = 1;
for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    x = !x;    
    $("body").append(x+"<br />");
}​
```

Comment: It's a boolean operator, what did you expect?

Comment: Okay, didn't knew that ;)! Upvoted all answers thanks.

Comment: You can force it to display as 0/1 if you are interested by casting to a Number. `x = Number(!x);`

Comment: Well, I didn't need a solution for this, just was curious why it is so, when it displays true/false instead of 1/0 :)

Comment: Look here, second step: http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.9

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because the ! operator coerces the value to a bool when it does its job.

Comment: Damn, too slow... +1 for being first.

Answer (score 12):

Because the "!" operator casts type of the variable to bool. You probably want to do:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 20; ++i) {
    $("body").append( String(i % 2) + '<br />');
}​
```

What's happening here? `%` is a modulo division operator. `i % 2` means "divide `i` by 2 and return the **remainder**".

`i % 2` is always either 1 or 0 (remainder in division by 2 is always 0 or 1).

Comment: One could also use `x = +!x;` to get a numeric value.

Comment: Agree, that yield the same result. However, in my opinion, this solution is more cryptic. Newcomers will have trouble understanding what's the intention behind `+!x` and thus I recommend using a more explicite version.

Answer (score 4):

Because by evaluating `x = !x;` you are changing the the type to a boolean instead of an integer.

Answer (score 4):

Because of the negation operator **!**.

It will return false if the argument is true and vice versa.

In this case 0 is cast to false first, 1 is cast to true. Then these values will be negated.

Answer (score 4):

`!` is a [boolean logic operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) and will return a boolean. To convert `true`/`false` back to `1`/`0`, you can use the [unary `+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_%28Unary_Plus%29):

```
x = 1;
for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    x = +!x;    
    $("body").append(x+"<br />");
}​
```

However, @Miszy's answer with the `mod 2` [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.25_%28Modulus%29) is more elegant and concise.